# Is there a way to notify the server that the app has been terminated?

Tags: ios, swift, terminate

I wrote the code to send a URLRequest to applicationWillTerminate, but learned that it was wrong.
Is there any other way to notify the server that the app has been terminated?
The code below receives and returns the data returned from the server, but since it only notifies the server of the end of the application, it is not necessary in principle.

```
 func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    appExitRequest()
}

func appExitRequest() {
    let settings = UserDefaults.standard
    let id = settings.string(forKey: myId)

    guard let myId = id?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {
        return
    }


    guard let req_url = URL(string: "http://localhost/test.php/terminate?myId=\(myId)") else {
        return
    }
    print(req_url)
    let req = URLRequest(url: req_url)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
        do {
            print("OK", data ?? "Empty")
        } catch {
            print("Failure", error)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: try logging the time it terminated and send that info to server once the app is launched again?

Comment: Certainly, there is also such a method. However, because we want to record only active users in the database, we can not wait for the app to be restarted.

Comment: why don't you just use some kinda analytics engine (Adobe, Firebase, etc...) to monitor the number of active sessions? those are advanced enough to give you accurate KPIs in commercial environment.

Comment: It is necessary to identify individual users, not the total number of users. Can Firebase do that?

Comment: You can use socket here, sending a socket message would be faster, and a smaller task, than the URLRequest.

Comment: I will try it. I've never done that, so please tell me which sites have code that would be helpful if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This is the only function available to call API to tell that app is terminated.

Comment: Is that so ... How can I send a URLRequest within this function?

Comment: make a API call in the background thread inside this function.Surely that will work.i tried with websockets to inform server that this user is now offline & it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much.I learn about websocket. Could you show me the code if you do not mind?

Comment: I'm sorry don't have the code now, i have left my previous company.

Comment: Thank you very much.I am going to use it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

`applicationWillTerminate` will not be called when the user terminates the app by swiping up the app in Task switcher. 
It will be called only when iOS watchdog process kills your app for any reasons like high memory consumption etc.

So, still your use case will not be completely handled if you trust on this method.
Also, there is no native callback method exposed by Apple as of now to handle this scenario.